# Which CPU are using AT&T assembly now?

Tags: assembly

I'm just curious if **AT&T** assembly syntax now only exists in software...

Comment: IMO it's not such a "not real" question. It's not perfectly worded, but otherwise quite reasonable.

Comment: No syntax does exist as hardware, unless you print out some syntax definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Syntax is how you write stuff down, it's not closely related to the command set or data model of the processor.

For example, you can write the very same sequence of code for an x86 chip in either AT&T or Intel syntax assemblers and it will run identically - the only major difference you'll see is that in AT&T syntax the destination is the second argument and in Intel syntax it is the first argument. Either will compile to the same very hard to read machine code.

Assembly language supported by Visual C++ for writing (hopefully) short asm blocks uses Intel syntax, while AFAIK assembly language supported by GCC uses AT&T syntax.

Comment: so it's a syntax only for software,which doesn't have anything to do with CPU itself?

Comment: It's only related to the compiler,right?

Comment: @DriverBoy: Yeap, the "assembly language" is just a convenient tool to write down programs, then that code is compiled to machine code and only the latter is executed.

Comment: when the compiler generates the machine code,it needs to know the type of CPU it's currently dealing with,right?Say,only the machine code generation process is related with CPU type?

Comment: @DriverBoy: Yes, it will only compile programs that are right for some specific CPU family, but that has almost nothing to do with AT&T syntax.